# Sign Ethereum contract transaction w/ web3 on back-end?

Tags: web3js, dapps, nodejs, private-key

How do I directly import via Private Key an account to the web3 library so it can get called by functions like myContract.methods.myMethod().call() & myContract.methods.myMethod().send()? I am not running my own node but rather use Infura.

Comment: With the stable web3 v0.20 it is possible to hookup [web3-provider-engine](https://github.com/MetaMask/provider-engine), so you can offload some services like signing. You can use [truffle with infura](http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/using-infura-custom-provider)  with such provider. But for web3 v1.0 they are not compatible yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What someone should do in this case is, as Ismael mentioned, use the web3-provider-engine. An example code snippet functioning with a custom private key and Infura API URL (Or even TestRPC) would be the following:

```
//Provider Engine sub-modules

const ProviderEngine = require('web3-provider-engine')
const CacheSubprovider = require('web3-provider-engine/subproviders/cache.js')
const FixtureSubprovider = require('web3-provider-engine/subproviders/fixture.js')
const FilterSubprovider = require('web3-provider-engine/subproviders/filters.js')
const VmSubprovider = require('web3-provider-engine/subproviders/vm.js')
const NonceSubprovider = require('web3-provider-engine/subproviders/nonce-tracker.js')
const RpcSubprovider = require('web3-provider-engine/subproviders/rpc.js')

//EthereumJS Wallet Sub-Provider

const WalletSubprovider = require('ethereumjs-wallet/provider-engine')
const walletFactory = require('ethereumjs-wallet')

//Web3 Module

const Web3 = require('web3')

//Wallet Initialization

var privateKey = "3a1076bf45ab87712ad64ccb3b10217737f7faacbf2872e88fdd9a537d8fe266"
var privateKeyBuffer = new Buffer(privateKey, "hex")
var myWallet = walletFactory.fromPrivateKey(privateKeyBuffer)

//Engine initialization & sub-provider attachment

var engine = new ProviderEngine();

engine.addProvider(new FixtureSubprovider({
  web3_clientVersion: 'ProviderEngine/v0.0.0/javascript',
  net_listening: true,
  eth_hashrate: '0x00',
  eth_mining: false,
  eth_syncing: true,
}))

// cache layer
engine.addProvider(new CacheSubprovider())

// filters
engine.addProvider(new FilterSubprovider())

// pending nonce
engine.addProvider(new NonceSubprovider())

// vm
engine.addProvider(new VmSubprovider())

// Here the URL can be your localhost for TestRPC or the Infura URL
engine.addProvider(new RpcSubprovider({
  rpcUrl: 'https://mainnet.infura.io/YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN',
}))

// Wallet Attachment
engine.addProvider(new WalletSubprovider(myWallet))

// network connectivity error
engine.on('error', function(err){
  // report connectivity errors
  console.error(err.stack)
})

// start polling for blocks
engine.start()

//Actual Initialization of the web3 module

var web3 = new Web3(engine)
```